# raster output name capture from Input data in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7

In writing a Python script, where I want to  capture last 3 digits from the  input raster's name and assign it to output raster name.

For Example:  My Input file names are: `Mean_Temp_001.tif`, `Mean_Temp_002.tif` so on, `Mean_Temp_012.tif`. After a calculation based on input data, I want to name the output raster based on the input.

```
for inRaster in list:
    localRaster = Raster(inRaster)
    outRaster = (localRaster/5)**1.514
    tifname = inRaster[3:]  # ( trying to captures "001" for output tiff name, as input name Mean_Temp_001.tif, Mean_Temp_002.tif)
    print tifname

    HI_OUT= os.path.join(outFolder, 'Heat_Index_{0}.tif'.format(tifname))
    outRaster.save(HI_OUT)
```

**Updated code as per suggestion, its not producing any output** its only printing 001, 002, 003 at the end of script,

```
    for inRaster in list:
        localRaster = Raster(inRaster)
        outRaster = (localRaster/5)**1.514
        file_name_only = os.path.splitext(inRaster)[0]
        tifname = file_name_only[-3:]

        HI_OUT= os.path.join(outFolder,'Heat_Index_{0}.tif'.format(tifname))
        outRaster.save(HI_OUT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's get the filename without the extension first:

```
import os

file_name_only = os.path.splitext(inRaster)[0]
```

Now we want the last three characters:

```
tifname = file_name_only[-3:]
```

[Python splicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/2258) can work from the end using negative numbers.

To print out the full path, add a `print` of the `HI_OUT` variable:

```
HI_OUT= os.path.join(outFolder, 'Heat_Index_{0}.tif'.format(tifname))
print(HI_OUT)
outRaster.save(HI_OUT)
```

Comment: I used this statement `last_three = file_name_only[-3:]`, its only producing  single output name multiple times and overwriting . the output name Heat_Index_tif.tif

Comment: I changed the variable name to match yours.  I must be missing something because it should work.

Comment: I have updated my code, updated code i posted above. after updating the code its not producing any output.

Answer (score 2):

I like to split strings by a character using `.split()`, when available. For example:

```
rasters = ['Mean_Temp_001.tif','Mean_Temp_002.tif','Mean_Temp_003.tif']

for r in rasters:
    part = r.split('.')[0].split('_')[2]
    out_raster = 'Heat_Index_' + part + '.tif'
    print out_raster
```

---

```
Heat_Index_001.tif
Heat_Index_002.tif
Heat_Index_003.tif
>>>
```

Comment: You're not using `os` here, only `str.split()`

Comment: Thanks for catching that @GISGe. Post edited with the fix.